# Need mysql query to find total sum as per matched query

Tags: mysql

I need to find sum of specific columns as per matched some of columns value in database table.

Please check mysql table that i use :

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `plant_production_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plant_production_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `materialid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `packaging_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slabs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `material_purchase_id` (`plant_production_id`),
  KEY `grade_id` (`grade_id`),
  KEY `packaging_id` (`packaging_id`),
  KEY `slabs` (`slabs`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=104 ;
```

Value are as under :

```sql
INSERT INTO `plant_production_items` (`id`, `plant_production_id`, `materialid`, `packaging_id`, `grade_id`, `slabs`) VALUES
(5, 4, 22, 85, 29, 4444),
(6, 5, 22, 14, 25, 3234),
(8, 6, 27, 21, 60, 4444),
(11, 8, 22, 85, 29, 44444),
(19, 7, 22, 84, 29, 434),
(75, 10, 26, 0, 51, 1233),
(76, 10, 24, 17, 34, 251),
(78, 10, 26, 0, 46, 3234),
(91, 9, 27, 21, 57, 1000),
(92, 9, 27, 21, 57, 2000),
(93, 3, 23, 16, 32, 5000),
(94, 3, 27, 21, 54, 3233),
(101, 3, 27, 21, 0, 700),
(103, 3, 29, 27, 0, 6666);
```

I want total sum of 'slabs' columns as per unique value founded in following column :

`plant_production_id`
  `materialid`
  `packaging_id` 
  `grade_id`

In short we need to find combination of all 4 values of above and need to show total sum of 'slabs' column.

For example :

there are two records which are same:

```
(91, 9, 27, 21, 57, 1000),
(92, 9, 27, 21, 57, 2000),
```

so here i want to get total sum i.e **1000+2000 = 3000**

Out put should be all columns with total slabs.    It is not required we need to match all above 4 columns. Actually we need to find all total slabs as per total records found same with above 4 column.

If still not clear then let me know.

Comment: I am not clear what your desired output would look like - can you add to question please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **GROUP BY** like this:

```sql
SELECT
plant_production_id,
materialidm,
packaging_id,
grade_id,
SUM(`slabs`) slabs_sum
FROM plant_production_items
GROUP BY plant_production_id, materialidm, packaging_id, grade_id;
```

So it gives the sum of the `slabs` for rows with the same values for columns grouped by.

Comment: @DaxaPatel Don't forget upvote and accept as answer